# If user is not logged in - Redirect to My account for registration: After logged in, some pages still redirect to my account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

If you're not logged in, the code works as intended: You get redirected to the my-account page. The contact page however, (PageID 19) you should be able to access. However, the "/" url (home) is sending the user into loop and/or sending the person back to the my-account page.

Producs/Product-categories can be accessable, so can cart and checkout. The shop (which is also set as static page) and terms & Condition can not be accessed.

The code have worked flawelessly, then stopped working as intended. Can you spot the error?

> EDIT: Now getting This page isn’t working. Site has redirected you too
>   many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

```
function not_logged_in_redirect() {
if ((! is_page(19) || ! is_page(39)) && !is_user_logged_in())  { // If it's not Contact or My account page adn the user is not logged in

       // Redirect user if not logged in, to My-account

        wp_redirect( get_permalink( 39 ) );

       exit;

   }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'not_logged_in_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use (! is_page(19) && ! is_page(39) instead of ||.